Determine if two conjugacy classes contain inverse elements in GAP
In GAP is there an O(1) way to write  Difference(List(c1, x -> x^-1), AsList(c2)) = []; where c1 and c2 are conjugacy classes of a subgroup of the Rubik's cube group and have the same cycle structure? Although I don't know how to prove this expression's correctness Representative(c1)^-1 in c2 and Representative(c2)^-1 in c1; seems to work. It's a bit faster but still O(n), and something tells me if just one element is inversed then all of them are.
To simplify, given two conjugacy classes of a subgroup of the Rubik's cube group that have the same cycle structure, is there a quick way to determine if the elements in the first conjugacy class are the inverses of the elements in the second class? I highly doubt there isn't a fast group theoretic approach for this problem but I'm not sure what to do.
Here's some GAP code to further elaborate what I'm talking about
gap> # taken from https://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/homes/GAP/WWW2/Doc/Examples/rubik.html
gap> U := ( 1, 3, 8, 6)( 2, 5, 7, 4)( 9,33,25,17)(10,34,26,18)(11,35,27,19);;
gap> L := ( 9,11,16,14)(10,13,15,12)( 1,17,41,40)( 4,20,44,37)( 6,22,46,35);;
gap> F := (17,19,24,22)(18,21,23,20)( 6,25,43,16)( 7,28,42,13)( 8,30,41,11);;
gap> R := (25,27,32,30)(26,29,31,28)( 3,38,43,19)( 5,36,45,21)( 8,33,48,24);;
gap> B := (33,35,40,38)(34,37,39,36)( 3, 9,46,32)( 2,12,47,29)( 1,14,48,27);;
gap> D := (41,43,48,46)(42,45,47,44)(14,22,30,38)(15,23,31,39)(16,24,32,40);;
gap> cube := Group(U, L, F, R, B, D);;
gap> my_subgroup := Stabilizer(cube, [1..15], OnTuples);
gap> r := Random(my_subgroup);;
gap> IsSubgroup(SymmetricGroup(48), my_subgroup);
true
gap> IsSymmetricGroup(my_subgroup);
false
gap> c1 := ConjugacyClass(my_subgroup, r);;
gap> c2 := ConjugacyClass(my_subgroup, r^-1);;
gap> c1 = c2;
false
gap> CycleStructurePerm(r) = CycleStructurePerm(r^-1);
true
gap> # say you aren't given how c1 and c2 were constructed
gap> # This hangs when performed on cube instead of my_subgroup. Can this be faster?
gap> Difference(List(c1, x -> x^-1), AsList(c2)) = [];
true


If $G$ is any group and $C$ a conjugacy class of $G$, then there is a well defined inverse conjugacy class $C^{-1} = \{x^{-1}: x \in C\}$. This is easy to show because if $x$ and $y$ are conjugate, say $y = gxg^{-1}$, then inverting both sides of that equation shows that $x^{-1}$ and $y^{-1}$ are conjugate. So Representative(c1)^-1 in c2 is correct. I'm not sure you can do better than that because your operation certainly can't be done faster than the in operation, i.e., checking whether two elements are conjugate.

Doh, this seemed obvious in retrospect. Thanks!

I don't understand why, but \in for ConjugacyClass objects seems to be O(1). The source code is beyond me

The method used for \in depends on the kid of group you have. In general it will require a conjugacy test and thus not be $O(1)$.
